# Could not load configuration file public_html/app/Config/facebook.php

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Iam trying to implement basic Facebook functionality in my CakePHP project. Iam getting the following error:

[image]

I did a bit of digging and turns out **/public_html/app/Config/facebook.php** is the wrong location for my CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin. My CakePHP is  actually located in **/public_html/app/Plugin/Facebook//Config/facebook.php** funny thing is i just cant get a clue were CakePHP is getting that wrong location.

Also iam using the

- CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin ver 3.1.3 (latest)
- CakePHP Framework version 2.5.4 (old)

I am also running this on a Hostinger Free subdomain account and some people suggested CURL could be an issue with free accounts BUT it seems enabled on the PHP configuration settings.

Comment: **https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/tree/v3.1.2#once-installed-if-you-wish-to-use-any-other-features-other-than-the-share-button-youll-need-to-get-an-api_key-and-secret-for-your-application**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED, Had to move the facebook.php file to app/config/